# ERROR --> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: java, sql, oracle, dbeaver

I have an issue that is generated randomly (one time between thousandth of calls). The error ORA-01722: invalid number is generated in a random way while executing sql update in a prepared statement Oracle database.

Although i think my code is correct but then also it is showing error,So please tell me where i am wrong.

here is my code:

```
    select *
from 
(
select p.*, SD.GLORGANIZATION
from     EXT.INNOVA_STANDING_ORDER_PAYMENT p , EXT.STANDINGORDER_DEFINITION SD,PRM.PRM_CORP_STANDING_ORDER_DEF SOD
where    p.status=1 and p.transfersequence in (?) and p.sirano=? 
and p.paymentstatus in ( ? ) 
AND P.CORPORATION=SOD.INNOVACODE AND P.SERVICEINFO=SD.SUBSCRIBERNO AND SD.CORPORATECODE=SOD.CODE AND SD.ORDERSTATU IN ('22') AND SD.STATUS=1
AND P.DUEDATE=? and P.CORPORATION not in ('10000','203','500','501','405','213')
union all
select p.*, SD.GLORGANIZATION
from     EXT.INNOVA_STANDING_ORDER_PAYMENT p , EXT.STANDINGORDER_DEFINITION SD,PRM.PRM_CORP_STANDING_ORDER_DEF SOD
where    p.status=1 and p.transfersequence in (?) and p.sirano=? 
and p.paymentstatus in ( ? ) 
AND P.CORPORATION=SOD.INNOVACODE AND P.SERVICEINFO=SD.SUBSCRIBERNO2 || SD.SUBSCRIBERNO AND SD.CORPORATECODE=SOD.CODE AND SD.ORDERSTATU IN ('22') AND SD.STATUS=1
AND P.DUEDATE=? and P.CORPORATION  in ('203','213','221')
union all
select p.*, SD.GLORGANIZATION 
from     EXT.INNOVA_STANDING_ORDER_PAYMENT p , EXT.STANDINGORDER_DEFINITION SD,PRM.PRM_CORP_STANDING_ORDER_DEF SOD
where    p.status=1 and p.transfersequence in (?) and p.sirano=? 
and p.paymentstatus in ( ? ) 
AND P.CORPORATION=SOD.INNOVACODE AND P.SERVICEINFO=SD.SUBSCRIBERNO AND
P.CORPACCOUNTID=SD.CORPACCOUNTID AND
SD.CORPORATECODE=SOD.CODE AND SD.ORDERSTATU IN ('22') AND SD.STATUS=1
AND P.DUEDATE=? and P.CORPORATION  in ('500','501')
union all
select p.*, SD.GLORGANIZATION 
from     EXT.INNOVA_STANDING_ORDER_PAYMENT p , EXT.STANDINGORDER_DEFINITION SD,PRM.PRM_CORP_STANDING_ORDER_DEF SOD
where    p.status=1 and p.transfersequence in (?) and p.sirano=? 
and p.paymentstatus in ( ? ) 
AND P.CORPORATION=SOD.INNOVACODE AND P.SERVICEINFO=SD.SUBSCRIBERNO AND 
P.SERVICEINFO2=to_number(SD.SUBSCRIBERNO2) AND SD.CORPORATECODE=SOD.CODE AND SD.ORDERSTATU IN ('22') AND SD.STATUS=1
AND P.DUEDATE=? and P.CORPORATION  in ('405') AND SD.CORPORATECODE='405'
union all
select p.*, SD.GLORGANIZATION 
from ( SELECT iso.* 
FROM EXT.INNOVA_STANDING_ORDER_PAYMENT iso
WHERE iso.CORPORATION IN('10000')
ORDER BY iso.billnumber )p, EXT.STANDINGORDER_DEFINITION SD, PRM.PRM_CORP_STANDING_ORDER_DEF SOD
WHERE p.status = 1
AND P.CORPORATION = SOD.INNOVACODE
AND P.SERVICEINFO = SD.SUBSCRIBERNO
AND P.SERVICEINFO2 = TO_NUMBER( SD.SUBSCRIBERNO2 )
AND SD.CORPORATECODE = SOD.CODE
AND SD.ORDERSTATU IN('22')
AND SD.STATUS = 1
AND P.CORPORATION IN('10000'))q
```

Comment: this error happened when you are trying to convert string to a number and the string can't be converted into a number

Answer (score 0):

"ORA-01722: invalid number" error may be raised during conversion varchar value to number. 
Typically, the problem usually occurs if you have '1,234' instead '1.234'.

For example:

```
select to_number('1,234') from dual;  -- ORA-01722 error 
select to_number('1.234') from dual;  -- correct
```

For resolving your problem you need to check numeric data in query source tables.

Please also note, that conversion to number may be executed without to_number(). If you use an operation between 2 different data types, one of them may be implicitly converted to another data type.

For example

```
select * 
from some_table 
where name +1 = 2;
```

name is VARCHAR field and should be converted to type NUMBER for execution +1 operation. In query plan you will see TO_NUMBER() operation.

```
filter(TO_NUMBER("NAME")+1=2)
```

There are a lot of numbers in quotes like '405' in your query. Looks like you have VARCHAR type for numeric columns.

```
SD.CORPORATECODE='405'
```

It may be a root cause of your problem, because you expect to have numbers in them, but may have any string in reality.